# Mathematica: Applying a function to a list of list

Tags: list, function, dictionary, wolfram-mathematica

I have a function `f[d_]`. My intention is to apply this function to a list as a whole.
Say, `d={1,2,3,...}`, then `f[d]` gives me a result (a number or whatever). Until here, everything is clear.

Now lets say I have the following list of lists: `p={l1,l2,l3,...}`
Is there a more efficient way than Map to compute `f[p]`, where the expected result is `{f[l1],f[l2],f[l3],...}`?

For example, with the `Sin[x]` function, Mapping it over a list is way slower than just putting the list inside its argument. This doesn't seem to work with my function `f[d]` and the list of lists p. What should I do to make that work? Would it be faster than Map?

To make myself clearer, say

```
f[d_]:=Total[d]
Then, f[{a1,a2,a3}] gives me a1+a2+a3, as expected.
But, f[{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}] kills the machine.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you require something like `Total[{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}, {2}]` ?

Comment: try working with the listable attribute: `SetAttribbutes[f,Listable]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change your code, It gives:

```
     Total[{{a1, b1, c1}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}]
     {a1 + b1 + c1, b1 + b2 + c2, b3 + c1 + c3}
```

When Total take a list argument, It just add the members, in your case, It adds

```
    {a1, b1, c1},{b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}
```

But they are not the same dimension, so you cant get the right answer.

In this case,Map should be used.

```
    Map[Total,{{a1, b1, c1}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}]
```

or

```
    Plus @@@ {{a1, b1, c1}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3, c4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Listable doesnt do the job here..
You can put map inside the function if it helps..

```
ClearAll[f]
f[d_List] := Map[ Total, d, {-2}]
f[{1, 2, 3}]
f[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
f[{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{6}, {7, 8}}}]

(* 6 *)
(* {6, 9} *)
(* {{6, 9}, {6, 15}} *)
```